# JAVA - Classloader can't find Applet main class

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I won't put all source code because it's really huge but I will try to explain my problem the best I can do.

I have an applet `com.dmp.applet.DMPApplet`, It's the main applet class and this one should be the first to load

`com.dmp.applet.DMPApplet`:

```
package com.dmp.applet;
// Imports

public class DMPApplet extends Applet
{
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        this.state = AppletState.OFF;
        this.running = true;

        CPSAPI.connector = (Cpsw32) Native.loadLibrary("cpsw32", Cpsw32.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void start()
    {
        CR_CPS cr = CR_CPS.fromShort(CPSAPI.connector.CPS_OuvertureSession(CPSAPI.pNomRessource, CPSAPI.pNomAppli, CPSAPI.pStatusService, CPSAPI.pNumSession.getReference(), CPSAPI.pFU.getReference()));
        System.out.println("OUVERTURE DE SESSION : " + cr.getMessage());

        this.jso = JSObject.getWindow(this);

        if(this.state == AppletState.OFF && this.running)
        {
            this.Attente_Connexion();
            this.Demande_Code_PIN();
        }

        if(this.state == AppletState.LOGGED && this.running)
        {
            this.Connexion_VS();
            this.Lancement_Gateway();
        }

        if(this.state == AppletState.READY && this.running)
        {
            this.Ecoute_Evenements_CPS();
            this.Fermeture();
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        CR_CPS cr = CR_CPS.fromShort(CPSAPI.connector.CPS_FermetureSession(CPSAPI.pNumSession.getValue(), CPSAPI.pStatusService));
        System.out.println("FERMETURE DE SESSION : " + cr.getMessage());
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

It's architecture is the basis for an applet to execute but when I test it under Eclipse (Juno) but every time I launch the project I get :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dmp.applet.DMPApplet.class
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:211)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:662)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Such a pain, I can't figure out what's happenning, the project works perfectly on another PC (the one my team mate use to develop), and it worked until two days ago...I have no clue...

Comment: My problem is gone, if I understand well the problem I had, it was the synchronisation between source file in Eclipse project and real source file (coming from svn). For some reason, restarting eclipse does not refresh source file...

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there's a ".class" on the end here is suspicious:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dmp.applet.DMPApplet.class
```

I'd expect this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dmp.applet.DMPApplet
```

How exactly are you launching it under Eclipse? (I've never written an applet in Eclipse.) If you have to specify the class anywhere, make sure you don't have the ".class" suffix, as it's not part of the class name.

Comment: No I don't have to specify class somewhere, just add libraries to build path and right-click > Run as... > "Java applet" on my DMPApplet.java file

Answer (score -1):

Can you please make sure that your jdk is properly configured in your application build path on eclipse. Right click on your application on eclipse and goto build path. Select libraries and ensure the jdk is there.

Comment: JDK 1.6.0_21 is in my libraries, I made a clean before compiling once again, the same exception...